# Ruby/Rails - Find Foreign Key With Most Instances in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys

I have a joined model that has a foreign key for the model event.

The joined model is called Goals.  I'm trying to find the proper find condition to figure out which event_id has the most instances in the Goal join model. Essenially which foreign key id has the most entries in the join model.

Is there a way to do this?

```
 Goal.where(:event.id => ??????? ).first
```

Comment: can you give us the code for your models concerned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't come up with a more elegant solution but try this:

```
results = Goal.connection.select_all('SELECT COUNT(*) as amount, event_id FROM goals GROUP BY event_id ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 0, xx')
raise results.inspect
```

If you just want the one most event_id with most entries you can also use:

```
event_id = Goal.connection.select_one('SELECT COUNT(*) as amount, event_id FROM goals GROUP BY event_id ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 1').first
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up your models correctly you should be able to do this (if this is not the case then: **setup your models correctly**):

```
if Event.all.length == 0
    return
end

eventMax = Event.first
Event.all.each do |e|
    eventMax = e.goals.length>eventMax.goals.length?e:eventMax
end

#output or do whatever with your newly found event
puts eventMax.to_json
```

The solution from Danny is not really good.

**You should never (or at least very rarely) have to write sql by yourself in rails.**

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, that you want the event with the most goals.